# sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: This text() construct doesn't define a bound parameter named 'current_time'

Tags: python, sql, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have the following function to check the reset token in table `reset_codes` using sqlalchemy and databases package(https://pypi.org/project/databases/)

```
def check_reset_token(reset_token: str):
    query = "SELECT * FROM reset_codes WHERE is_active=True AND reset_code=:reset_token " 
    "AND expired_in >= :current_time - INTERVAL '60 minutes'"
    return database.fetch_one(query, values={"reset_token": reset_token, "current_time": datetime.utcnow()})
```

i am getting the following error and not sure how to fix

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: This text() construct doesn't define a bound parameter named 'current_time'
```

here is what value of `expired_in` column looks like for the datetime

```
|         exired_in             |
| ----------------------------- |
| 2021-06-12 19:19:53.007063    |
```

so not sure if this is where the problem is `:current_time - INTERVAL '60 minutes'`

Answer (score 1):

fixed, was a typo!

```
def check_reset_token(reset_token: str):
    query = "SELECT * FROM reset_codes WHERE is_active=True AND reset_code=:reset_token AND expired_in >= :current_time - INTERVAL '60 minutes'"
    return database.fetch_one(query, values={"reset_token": reset_token, "current_time": datetime.utcnow()})
```

the sql query had `" "` and went to line 2...crazy missed that and spent several hours trying to figure it out